# Expectancy and variation of coin toss set

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is expectancy in the sense of sample mean and variance of this coin toss set

$$S=[1,1,0,1,0]$$

probability of $P(x=1)$ is $p$

Variance is $$var(S) = E(S^2) - E(S)^2$$

but I don't know how to calculate $E(S^2)$ given there are many 1's

Comment: are the answers E(S) is 3p ? and var(s) is $3p - (3p)^2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate E(S), the it happens $E(S^2)=E(S)$, since 0 and 1 are equal to their squares.

Comment: so E(S) is 3p ? and var(s) is $3p - (3p)^2$ ?

Comment: No, you've mixed up $S$ and $X$.  $S$ is defined to be *a posteriori* experimental result, so you just use high school stat to calculate $E[S^2] = E[S] = \dfrac35$, so $\mathrm{var}(S) = \dfrac35\cdot\dfrac25 = \dfrac{6}{25}$.